# How to find the correct page for wget to download from?

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

I want to download all *.pdf files on a website recursively.
What I could achieve so far is:

- Store the cookies needed for the login page with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget) question
- Download a specific file by copy and pasting the direct download link from my browser.
  Now I tried using the following command: 
  `wget --recursive --no-parent -A pdf --load-cookies cookies.txt https://example.com`

But I just got some empty folders, which leads me to believe I didn't use the correct link. How can I find the correct link for the recursive download?

Comment: --accept '*.pdf'      --user=<username>  --password=<password>

Comment: @pierrely What does this command do differently than mine? Can I not use cookies with a recursive download?

Comment: I am just suggesting an alternative to cookie issues if you have login details.
according to 

    wget --help | grep cookies

you might need an = sign there

--load-cookies=FILE         load cookies from FILE before session

as in --load-cookies=cookies.txt